# Scroll doesn't work in "text with autocomplete" in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to use "TExt with autocomplete" option for a field in oracle apex.
It works fine, in a way that when I type in something it gives me a list of values . But on the side it show a scroll bar , but when i click on the scrollbar to scroll down, the whole list disappears.

Can you please let me know how can i still scroll in the list, ater i have typed something in the text field.

Thanks,
Abha

Comment: No problem on my Apex 18.2. Which version do you use?

Comment: Oh..My APEX version is 18.1. and it doesn't work properly there !!

Comment: Log in to apex.oracle.com, which was recently updated to 20.1. See if you can reproduce the issue there.